# is there a way to Limit the number of times a function is called in one second using ruby?

Tags: ruby, time

I have a slow sql query, and I'd like to limit the number of times a function can be called in one second to (3).

Lets say I have these calls, I'd like the function to do that:

```
call_func() -> true
call_func() -> true
call_func() -> true
call_func() -> false
sleep(1)
call_func() -> true
```

I placed a limit of up to 3 calls per second, and then the timer is reset. How would you do this in ruby using `Process.clock_gettime(Process::CLOCK_MONOTOMIC)`

Comment: There are gems for this as well such as https://github.com/Shopify/limiter

Answer (score 0):

https://msp-greg.github.io/eventmachine/EventMachine/PeriodicTimer.html

Your code would look something like this:

```
n = 0
timer = EventMachine::PeriodicTimer.new(1) do
    call_func()
    timer.cancel if (n+=1) > 3
end
```

Though in truth I think the overhead of this alone will eat into some of the 1 second that you are allocating for the SQL query, so you might end up with a situation where the query only executes 1 or 2 times within the second allocated to the timer, and I couldn't begin to predict the resource increase (memory, etc.) that adding this would create.

You may be better off simply using Threads to handle the issue.  You would simply create a Thread for each query and whenever it completes, it completes.  Then you could restrict the Thread pool to manage the load.

https://rossta.net/blog/a-ruby-antihero-thread-pool.html